# Compare operation in Velocity does not execute True branch when it should

Tags: compare, velocity

In the operation below TRUE results will not execute the appropriate code branch ($set ($color = red), does anyone know why?

I have tried comparing ($percent_covered < 100), ($percent_covered < "100.000"), ($number.float($percent_covered) < $number.float("100.00")) and ($percent_covered < $number.float("100.00")).  I have also tried rearranging the operation but nothing seems to trigger the TRUE statement.

In this example $percent_covered is 18.73

```
#set ($percent_covered = $math.mul($div, 100))
    $percent_covered
    #if ($percent_covered < "100.000")
        $percent_covered
        #set ($color = "red")
    #else
        #set ($color = "green")
    #end
    <td class="$color percent">$number.format("#0.00", $percent_covered)%</td>
```

Comment: Which version of Velocity are you using? In v1.7 and v2.0 `$percent_covered < 100` works just fine for me.

Comment: Is this working for you when $percent_covered is 18.73?  I'm still working on getting the version of Velocity, in my case Velocity is the language used for scripting within a larger ALM tool.

Comment: Looks like the tool has implemented Apache Velocity 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

I had to force the $percent_covered to an integer.  To do this I made the following changes.  *Warning: This is not the most elegant solution, but it worked for me.*

```
#set ($Integer = 0)
#set ($div = $math.div($covered, $requirements.size))
#set ($percent_covered = $math.mul($div, 100))
#*
 Create a whole_number, as a string.
*#
#set ($whole_number = $number.format("#0", $percent_covered))

#* 
 Convert to integer
*# 
#if ($Integer.parseInt($whole_number) < 100)
    #set ($color = "red")
#else
    #set ($color = "green")
#end
<td class="$color percent">$number.format("#0.00", $percent_covered)%</td>
```